# Join Field Error (ERROR_000499 Table is not editable)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins

I'm trying to join a field from a table to a census tract shapefile based on the CT name field. I'm getting this error however:

[image]

Has anyone encountered this error before and possibly know where it's coming from?

Comment: Where are your two tables stored?

Comment: You are probably not allowed to change the input table. Maybe someone else is using it at the same time as you are?